# wso2 dss 3.2.2: select '?' from dual throws NullPointerException

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have datasource that requires `?` in the query but this is not a parameter.
But in case of using `?` DSS returns NullPointerException as fault message.
I can reproduce the error with simple sql query with internal H2 datasurce.

Query:

```
select '?' as c1 from dual
```

Result in the log:

```
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: ttttt
Location: \ttttt.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: q1
Current Params: {}
Nested Exception:-
java.lang.NullPointerException

        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery(SQLQuery.java:832)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.runPreQuery(SQLQuery.java:2301)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.Query.execute(Query.java:275)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.executeElement(CallQuery.java:188)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.OutputElement.execute(OutputElement.java:89)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.operation.Operation.execute(Operation.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DataService.invoke(DataService.java:474)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:96)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processDynamicQuery(SQLQuery.java:1395)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.createProcessedPreparedStatement(SQLQuery.java:1506)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery(SQLQuery.java:806)
        ... 50 more
```

Maybe there are some special parameters to force wso2dss not to parse query by itself and use database engine for parsing?